# Laravel sql server execute stored procedure with array parameter

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a very simple question; I have a query running perfectly on sql server and I want to run this query using laravel framework, here is the query:

```
DECLARE @countries AS countryList; 
    INSERT INTO @countries SELECT countries.id FROM countries where countries.id in (1,2,3,4,9,11,14);
    EXEC sp_positionofCourtCasesofLoanDefaultA @countries
```

in Laravel this is returning 'true' always

```
 $result = DB::statement('DECLARE @countries AS countryList; INSERT INTO @countries SELECT countries.id FROM countries where countries.id in (' . $countries . ');
 EXEC sp_positionofCourtCasesofLoanDefaultA @countries');

 dd($result);
```

please help.

Comment: In SQL server this stored procedure returns records but in laravel it returns boolean.

Answer (score 1):

i think DB:statement() returns either true or false. It is generally used in queries like insert in which no result is returned. So if the query was executed successfully it returns true otherwise returns false.